# Xam.Plugins.Notifier not work on IOS 11

Tags: notifications, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using Xam.Plugins.Notifier package to implement Local Notification in Xamarin.Forms project.

Here is the code what I wrote in PCL project.
CrossLocalNotifications.Current.Show("Title", "Description");

It works good on Android but It doesn't work on IOS.
I am not sure if it works on lower IOS sdk.
Anyway it doesn't work on IOS 11.

Here is the code that I added in AppDelegate.cs

```
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {
                // Ask the user for permission to get notifications on iOS 10.0+
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
                    UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
                    (approved, error) => { });
            }
            else if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                // Ask the user for permission to get notifications on iOS 8.0+
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                    new NSSet());

                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
            }
```

Can anybody help me to fix it?
I want to have this package working on IOS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which scenario does it not work ? Active or in background?

If it doesn't work when it is active , you may forget to handle the delegate (subclasses `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`)

Modify your code as below:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
{
    // Ask the user for permission to get notifications on iOS 10.0+
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(
        UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound,
        (approved, error) => { });

    // Watch for notifications while app is active
    UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();
}
```

Create a subclass `UserNotificationCenterDelegate`

```
public class UserNotificationCenterDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
{
    public override void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        // Tell system to display the notification anyway or use
        // `None` to say we have handled the display locally.
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I've already handled it myself. What should be added if it doesn't work when it's in background.

Comment: @Passionate.C The code you provided should work in background.